# Selenium Grid - Connecting Linux server and Windows/Mac machine

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, centos, selenium-grid2

We have a Continuous Integration, setup (Jenkins) on a Linux Server, CentOS 6, No GUI.

1. I have Setup a New job for Regression tests on this server too. The framework used is Java, Selenium WD, JUnit and Ant.
2. Test run fine on Headless browser config such as Firefox and PhantomJS. But I require a Browser for Testing Flash components/Player.
3. Using Selenium Grid when I make the server the "Hub" and my other Windows machine a "node"
   The connection is not established/connection timed out since they are not in the same network.

How do I bypass the firewall issue/How do I establish a connection and run my tests.

Comment: Is the "other windows machine" a slave on your jenkins setup?

Comment: @ShivaKumar no its not a slave on my Jenkins setup, So can I add a slave machine which is not in the same network? will that help?

Comment: If you wish to use Jenkins effectively, have all the test environment machines as slaves. If your windows machine is not in the network, use a machine that is in the network for testing or get you machine into the network. And also remember that for Selenium based UI testing, you need to connect to the client via Java web start